# Contradicting arguments regarding the ramification index of the splitting field of $X^3 - 135X - 270$ over $\mathbb{Q}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, ramification

Let $f = X^3 - 135X - 270 \in \mathbb{Q}_5[X]$ and $L$ the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}_5$.

Let $e$ be the ramification index of $L/\mathbb{Q}_5$. If I am not mistaken, the degree of $L/\mathbb{Q}_5$ is $6$, so $e \in \{1,2,3,6\}$.

**Argument 1**

Since $f \equiv X^3$ (mod $5$), we do not need to extend the residue field $\mathbb{F}_5$ of $\mathbb{Q}_5$, so $L/\mathbb{Q}_5$ is totally ramified. Or equivalently, $e=6$.

**Argument 2**

Let $\alpha \in L$ be a root of $f$. In the discussion of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745184/computing-the-reduction-of-a-quotient-over-the-5-adic-numbers), we see that $L$ is also the splitting field of the polynomial $$g = \frac 1 {\alpha^3} f(\alpha x) = x^3 - \frac {135}{\alpha^2} x - \frac{270}{\alpha^3}$$.

From the same post I mentioned, the reduction of $g$ modulo the uniformizer $\alpha$ of the intermediate field $\mathbb{Q}_5(\alpha)$ is
$$\bar{g} = g \mod \alpha  = x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 + x + 1).$$

The second factor has no roots over $\mathbb{F}_5$ (the residue field of $\mathbb{Q}_5(\alpha)$), so in order for $\bar{g}$ to split over $\mathbb{F}_5$, we must extend the residue field, so $e < 6$.

We see here that these arguments are contradicting each other. Could you please explain me which one is correct/wrong and if one is wrong why that is the case?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see why you can reduce modulo $\alpha$ given that $g$ contains coefficients whose "$\alpha$-adic" valuation, so to speak, is negative. Could I get some clarification on that?

Comment: @Azhao17: Sorry that I did not mention it! It was also an observation from the post I mentioned at the beginning of Argument 2.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for pointing me to the reference!

Comment: Your argument 2 is perfect as it stands. Argument $1$ would show that the splitting field of *any* Eisenstein polynomial was totally ramified, certainly false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argument 1 is wrong. That the minimal polynomial of *some* generating element of the field extension reduces to something which has all its roots in the residue field proves nothing about the extension. Actually, by replacing a primitive element $\alpha$ with $p^n \alpha$ for high enough $n$, we can achieve such a minimal polynomial which just reduces to some power of $x$. As an easy example, look at the unramified extension $\mathbb Q_5(\sqrt2)=\mathbb Q_5(5\sqrt2)$ and consider the minimal polynomial $x^2-50$. Modulo $5$ it's just $x^2$.

The same flawed argument came up in the question [Line of arguments for showing why some extension is quartic and unramified](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3571530/96384), compare my more detailed answer there.

Comment: Quite right, as I point out in my comment above.